# Htaccess query string

Tags: string, .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I am trying to make:

```
http://www.specialisedorthoticservices.co.uk/image.php?object_type=detailed&image_id=140&window=popup
```

become this:

```
http://www.specialisedorthoticservices.co.uk
```

The result of the query no longer exists and the re-direct doesn't seem to work see code below:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/image\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^object_type=detailed&image_id=140&window=popup$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.specialisedorthoticservices.co.uk [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the slash before image.php. In fact, why not just shorten it? To not append the query string you need a terminating question mark like so

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^object_type=detailed&image_id=140&window=popup$
RewriteRule ^image\.php$ /? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I have added the ? it still ignores the rule when visiting the page

Comment: Sorry forgot the slash part, on my phone its not easy to copy paste code

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response but still no joy

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^object_type=detailed&image_id=140&window=popup$
RewriteRule ^/image\.php$ http://www.specialisedorthoticservices.co.uk? [R=301,L]

Comment: Are you putting ^/image like you just wrote or no slash ^image like I put?

Comment: Yes there are other redirects before it and before the first one I have enabled rewrite engine.

I have other rewriteconditions written in the same way that work which is strange

Comment: try moving this rule to the top just below RewriteEngine On in case one of the other rules was interfering. If not I don't know what to say, I tested this on my own server and it redirects fine

Comment: No Joy thanks for your help though.  I cant understand why it doesn't work.  It may be because there is more than one '=' sign in the string

Comment: that shouldnt be causing it, if you comment out the RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} line does it redirect image.php?

Comment: Figured it out.  Although it still displays the long query string in the address bar, it now re-directs to the home page I added the following